# If I have a function that's continuous and it's limits at $\pm \infty$ are $\pm \infty$ is it surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions

I was trying out some problems where I needed to prove that a function was surjective, and I thought I could do this, is this true? Intuitively, it seems so.

If I have a function that's continuous and it's limits at $\pm \infty$ are $\pm \infty$ is it surjective?

Comment: Yes, assuming that one limit is $-\infty$ and the other is $+\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Fix $v \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$, there exists $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a) < v$. Since $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$, there exists $b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(b) > v$. Now apply the intermediate value theorem.